# Tkinter outputting KeyError when Updating Multiple Matplotlib Objects

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, tkinter

I am somewhat new to python animation, and I'm getting the following error when I try to update multiple `matplotlib` 2D objects in `FuncAnimation`

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 745, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 95, in _on_timer
    TimerBase._on_timer(self)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1382, in _on_timer
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1542, in _step
    still_going = Animation._step(self, *args)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1277, in _step
    self._draw_next_frame(framedata, self._blit)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1296, in _draw_next_frame
    self._draw_frame(framedata)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1814, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
  File "<ipython-input-73-4c78ddeac2f8>", line 10, in animate
    moving_x = [0, orbradii[ii]*np.cos(angle)]
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 623, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2557, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 83, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 811, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 817, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

Following is the code that I wrote to animate orbital motion. I have been running this in `python 3.6` using `TkAgg` as the backend.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
orbradii = df['radii']
planet_total = len(orbradii)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, xlim=(-max(orbradii), max(orbradii)), ylim=(-max(orb_radii), max(orb_radii)))

lines = []
for _ in range(planet_total):
    lines.append(ax.plot([], [], 'o'))

def init():
    #set the data to empty lists for the x, y coordinates, respectively
    for ii in range(len(lines)):
        print(lines[ii])
        lines[ii][0].set_data([], [])
    return lines

def animate(i):
    angle = i/10. * np.pi

    for ii in range(planet_total):
        moving_x = [0, orbradii[ii]*np.cos(angle)]
        moving_y = [0, orbradii[ii]*np.sin(angle)]

        #set the x, y coordinates to these new values
        print(lines[ii])
        lines[ii][0].set_data(moving_x, moving_y)

    return lines

our_animation = ani.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 1000), interval=75, init_func=init)

plt.show()
```

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Tom's comment, I realized that if I convert the `orbradii` variable to values, my code works.

```
orbradii = df['radii'].values
```

Comment: You code works for me (once I made the names of `orb_radii` and `orbradii` consistent). However, this doesn't appear to be the code you ran to produce that error trace, since that stems from `pandas`, which you don't use in this example.

Comment: @tom Thank you! I originally had my variable coming from a dataframe, and I edited my code above to reflect that. Your comment helped me realize that converting the column to values would allow the animation to work.